# Do core.async go blocks park themselves, or is there a 'scheduler'?

Tags: clojure, core.async

As I understand it, on the JVM there is a thread pool available to the core.async go blocks with `n + 2` number of threads, where `n` is the number of cores on the machine.

However, many go blocks can be deployed on one thread at the same time. Each is either in a parked state (which means its computation is not progressing) or in a running state (wherein its computation is buzzing around a core generating heat). If there are 1000 go blocks on a quad-core machine then I guess that there are a maximum of 6 of these 1000 go blocks in a running state at any one time. The other 994 go blocks must therefore be parked.

Full Threads are scheduled onto a core; either by the OS scheduler or by a JVM supervisor thread. So how does a go block enter/exit the parked state? Does it decide to park itself when it gets bored of running (blocks) or is there a supervisor thread acting as a 'go block scheduler' which determines which go block is running on which thread and subject to some scheduling algorithm such as Round Robin etc.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're mixing up `core.async`'s channels with its IOC "threads" which you can create using the `go` macro. Channels don't actually *do* anything, so they aren't ever in a running or parked state.

Comment: `core.async`'s *go blocks* park at certain points where parking operations are used. These are the points in which the `core.async` compiler can park these blocks. If you do some blocking IO operation inside a go block, that is not one of the operations provided by core.async, then you will block one of threads in core.async's thread pool. This is what I understood from Timothy Baldrige's videos Macro Internals [part I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3PZMIwXN_g) and [part II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SI7qtuuahhU). Both are very interesting.

Comment: @user3231690 I updated the question so that the question refers to go blocks and not to channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They park themselves.

The `go` macro walks the entire form, finds the places where it will need to park, and explicitly puts in calls to park the thread in these spots. Some of the common ones are are:

- the start of other go blocks
- taking from a chan `<!`
- sending to a chan `>!`
- calls to `async/thread`

This is a big part of the reason go blocks can't span function calls. the compiler/macro needs to be able to see the whole block of code to put these in the correct places.

Comment: Potential typo: "function calls" -> "function definitions"

Comment: Thanks Arthur - so does this mean that go blocks are not the best place to do IO/network stuff - the macro would not know how long to block for if the go block is waiting on a webservice call to return..

Comment: Always use async/thread for them and your fine. (Until you run out of total threads on the system of course, or run out of memory)  I use it daily for db calls and calls to other services.

Comment: To be clear, if a go block would make blocking calls it should be a call to thread instead. They are otherwise identical